# How to add a value to a data frame which has given columns and rows

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I would like to ask some values in the data frame. Here is my code:

I have the code as

```
algorithm_choice =['DUMMY','LINEAR_REGRESSION','RIDGE_REGRESSION','MLP','SVM','RANDOM_FOREST']     m

model_type_choice=['POPULATION_INFORMED','REGULAR','SINGLE_CYCLE','CYCLE_PREDICTION'] 

rmse_summary=pd.DataFrame(columns=algorithm_choice, index = model_type_choice)
```

How can I add a specific value to rmse_summary?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)

To add a specific value, I assume one value, then you can use either .loc or .iloc.

.loc will give you a specific position by name:

```
rmse_summary.loc['REGULAR','DUMMY'] = 3
```

.iloc will give you access to a position by index number:

```
rmse_summary.iloc[2,4] = 5
```